# Ansible: Find unused inventory files

Tags: ansible

With a growing inventory, probability of no longer needed files in the inventory rises.
Harmless Example: Some developer removed copying of `file_a` from task file  role `xxx`, but forgot to delete `file_a`.

How can I detect such files?